# Civ 5 - How do i enable world wrap on a fractal or pangea map (not world builder)

Tags: civilization-5

How do i enable world wrap because i always spawn on the opposite side of the map than my teammate. Is there a mod or something? I heard using ige (In game editor) could work? 
(Instructions please if its to complicated)

Answer (score 6):

East/west world wrap is always (or default at least) enabled. As far as I know there is no possibility to have a north/south world wrap. There is always a north and southpole.